# How do I change screen resolution?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display, resolution

I am unable to change my screen resolution in my ubuntu 12.04. My default screen resolution was 1366x768. I had executed nvidia-xconfig to activate NVIDIA driver. Since then my screen resolution has stuck on 640x480.
I have tried going to Display settings, but it shows only one option in the drop down menu.
`xrandr -s 1366x768` is also not working.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the resolution from NVIDIA's display configuration panel?
Remember to run it as 'sudo' in order to save your settings:

1) Hit <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>

2) type `gksudo nvidia-settings` and hit enter ('gksudo' is the GUI version of the 'sudo' command in the terminal; alternatively you could open a terminal window and type "sudo nvidia-settings").

3) Select the resolution you want then hit `apply`, and if it looks good, click `save to x-config`

If nothing happens when you try to run the nvidia-settings program, perhaps you need to download and the latest drivers from NVIDIA's website.

Let us know how that goes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is what how it went:

![This is what I got when I entered nvidia-settings as root][1]

I suppose it means my nvidia-xconfig didn't quiet work as expected.
Nevertheless, I am unable to change screen resolution through system settings.
Also, there is no resolution option in nvidia-settins window

![This is my nvidia settings window][2]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/pOLig.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TBfME.png

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but you did run nvidia-xconfig as sudo, right?  I've never seen it blank like that; have you tried downloading and installing the latest drivers from NVIDIA?

Comment: yes. I did run it as sudo. Also tried installing latest drivers from NVIDIA. Didn't make any difference.