# Ubuntu 18.04 only showing one screen resolution option

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, screen, display-resolution

My settings only show one screen resolution in Ubuntu 18.04 :

[image: "Resolution" dropdown only showing 1920 x 1080 (16:9)]

`xrandr -q` gives one resolution, as you can see. For my second screen, many resolutions are available.

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 162mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  48.03  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I tried the answer from [this response](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256928/how-do-i-change-screen-resolution) but what I got is:

[image: PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool.]

> PRIME Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings and must be configured by an external RandR capable tool.

That means I cannot control the displays thanks to nvidia settings. So I believe I have to use a RandR capable tool but I have no idea how. Must of all, I had no idea it'd be so difficult to change my screen resolution. How should I do it?

EDIT thanks to comments: my laptop is a Dell XPS 7390.

Comment: I am assuming that display is your laptop built-in screen? What is the make/model of the laptop? According to the manufacturers specifications you need to find out what screen resolutions and refresh rates are supported. It may be that the screen only supports that single resolution. It's possible to add more resolutions/refresh rates using `xrandr` on the command line but you don't want to go adding resolutions/refresh rates that are not supported.

Comment: @codlord, yes it's my laptop built-in screen's display. My laptop is a DELL XPS 7390 and I have no idea how to know which resolution it supports nor how to use `xrandr`...

Comment: If you run `man xrandr` on the terminal it should show you the manual pages for the command and all the options. And I am guessing you can use a search engine? :-) So search the web for `DELL XPS 7390` go to the Dell website and download the specs/manuals. But I suspect 1920x1080 is the native resolution of the screen and generally you don't want to set a resolution higher than a monitors native resolution. The native resolution is the best quality you will get.

Comment: @codlord, actually I want to set a lower resolution than 1920x1080. I'd like to permanently zoom into my screen because it is too small compared to my other HDMI monitor. I'm surprised that I should use xrandr. Thus reading the man. I thought there be an easier way.

Comment: Most monitors would support lower resolutions by default and in which case you would be able to select them via Ubuntu settings very easily. Modern monitors will report to the OS all the resolutions they support. I don't know why that screen does not report any lower resolutions.

Comment: @codlord, thank you anyway for your comments. I think that's the purpose of my bounty :)